# How to fix HTTP response header injection/HTTP Response Splitting

Tags: java, security

I have a J2EE web application for which a scan using Burp Scanner Suite reported the following as a HTTP response header injection vulnerability.
The problem is when a CRLF character is injected in the request header/parameter, we are simply removing such characters from request so as to avoid Response Splitting issue but the Burp Scanner Suite still reports it as a high issue.

So my question is, "Is it not sufficient to simply remove CRLF characters from request to avoid HTTP Resonse Splitting issue and allow the request to proceed? or Should we throw an exception when such characters are found in request? How can it harm if CRLF characters has already been removed. Can someone explain with an example? [Screenshot of the issue reported by Burp Scanner ]: 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter the CRLF characters from user input is sufficient to rectify this finding. From your screenshot, it can show that this finding is not valid as it does not cause any newline in your response header.

If it is vulnerable, you suppose to see something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Tue, 21 Mar ....
...
...
Location: https://MachineName1.Domain1/base/home?1bqfh
ob2ym=1
...
```

> The **ob2ym=1** should appear as newline in the response header
>   because of the **%0d** character.

For you information, for security related question you can ask in [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com). I bet you will get more response from posting here.

I hope this can help you.